# The elements which when multiplied give us conjugation with respect to three cycles

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, symmetric-groups

Let $S_n$ be the symmetric group of order $n$ with $g_1,s\in S_{n-1}$ and $i,j\in\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$. Then, what is the general structure of elements $s$ such that the equation $$g_1s(1,2,n)g_1^{-1}=(i,j,n)$$
So, basically, it is like asking which elements when multiplied by $(1,2,n)$ to the right, are conjugate to $(i,j,n)$.

I know that elements having the same cycle structure are conjugate to each other. But, how do we determine that $s(1,2,n)$ will have the same structure. One trivial example for $s$ is the identity. But, are there other elements for $s$ as examples? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: $s$ could be $(2,1,x)$. This undoes the movement of item $1$, leaving only items $2$, $n$, and $x$ displaced as a 3-cycle.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis Are those the only elements?

Comment: I believe so. $s$ must be an even permutation, so $s$ permutes at least 3 items (unless it is the identity). The element $s$ cannot be $(1,2,n)$ itself since $s \in S_{n-1}$, so $s$ must involve at least one of the items other than $1$, $2$, and $n$. With at least 4 items now involved in the combined permutation, at least one of them must be returned to its home location to get back down to a 3-cycle. The only item that we can do that to is item $1$. It follows that $s$ permutes only one item outside of $\{1, 2\}$, so $s$ must be a 3-cycle that moves $2\rightarrow 1$.

Comment: @JaapScherphuis You could write this comment as an answer